# Copy different rows based Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I am trying to `auto-copy` `rows` from a master `worksheet` to a separate `worksheet`. This occurs when a specific value is entered into `Column B` in a Master `sheet`. E.g. if `ABC` is entered into `Column B` in Master, these `rows` will get auto-copied into a separate sheet called `ABC`.

The issue is I have other values I want to copy into other worksheets. E.g if `DEF` is entered in Column B in Master, then auto-copy into separate sheet called `DEF`. I dont know how to do this.

The code below automatically copies all rows when `Change` is entered into `Column B`. This works fine but I also want to add another function that `copies` all `rows` when 'Delay' is entered.

```
Sub FilterAndCopy()
    Dim rng As Range, sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet

    Set sht1 = Worksheets("Master")
    Set sht2 = Worksheets("Change")

sht2.UsedRange.ClearContents

With Intersect(sht1.Columns("B:BP"), sht1.UsedRange)
    .Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False ' unhide columns
    If .Parent.AutoFilterMode Then .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Change"

    .Range("A:F, BL:BO").Copy Destination:=sht2.Cells(4, "B")
    .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    .Range("H:BK").EntireColumn.Hidden = True ' hide columns
    End With
End Sub
```

That code just copies Change rows from the master sheet to change sheet.

However I want to add another function that copies Delay rows from the master sheet to delay sheet. I'm just not sure if this can be incorporated into the code above? Or if I can do the following:

```
Sub FilterAndCopy()
    Dim rng As Range, sht1 As Worksheet, sht3 As Worksheet

    Set sht1 = Worksheets("Master")
    Set sht3 = Worksheets("Delay")

sht3.UsedRange.ClearContents

With Intersect(sht1.Columns("B:BP"), sht1.UsedRange)
    .Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False ' unhide columns
    If .Parent.AutoFilterMode Then .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Delay"

    .Range("A:B, BJ:BO").Copy Destination:=sht2.Cells(4, "B")
    .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    .Range("D:BI").EntireColumn.Hidden = True ' hide columns
    End With
End Sub
```

**PLEASE NOTE:**
This macro has to be triggered without running a script.

Comment: See edit, everything is working fine on my test file.

Comment: Thanks for your help @O.PAL, but this doesnt copy 'all' rows. The macro isnt triggered either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back at it again.
Please note that this is tested and working so please double check before changing anything (like you did with B4 to B5 in the previous test).

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then

        Dim Sh1 As Worksheet: Set Sh1 = Me
        Dim Sh2 As Worksheet: Set Sh2 = Worksheets("CHANGE OF NO'S")
        Dim Sh3 As Worksheet: Set Sh3 = Worksheets("ECS")
        Dim R0 As Range
        Dim R1 As Range: Set R1 = Intersect(Sh1.UsedRange, Sh1.Columns(2))

        'Clear data in sheets
        Sh2.Cells.Clear
        Sh2.Range("B4") = "start"
        Sh3.Cells.Clear
        Sh3.Range("B4") = "start"

        'Clear autofilter
        If Sh1.AutoFilterMode Then Sh1.AutoFilterMode = False

        For Each R0 In R1
            Select Case Trim(R0.Value)
                Case Is = "Change"
                    Intersect(R0.EntireRow, Sh1.Range("A:F,BL:BO")).Copy Sh2.Cells(Sh2.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                Case Is = "Early"
                    Intersect(R0.EntireRow, Sh1.Range("A:D,O:R,BL:BO")).Copy Sh3.Cells(Sh3.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            End Select
        Next R0

        Sh2.Range("B4") = ""
        Sh3.Range("B4") = ""

    End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This is to be inserted on the "Master" sheet code or whatever you called it. See below:

[image]

Now the code will run when you type anything in column "B" in Master sheet. See below:

Sheet Master (Entering a new "Change" text in column "B"):

[image]

Updated sheets "CHANGE OF NO'S" and "ECS" :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest a slightly different approach :

```
Sub Copy_criteria()

    Dim Sh1 As Worksheet: Set Sh1 = Worksheets("SHIFT LOG")
    Dim Sh2 As Worksheet: Set Sh2 = Worksheets("CHANGE OF NO'S")
    Dim Sh3 As Worksheet: Set Sh3 = Worksheets("ECS")
    Dim R0 As Range
    Dim R1 As Range: Set R1 = Intersect(Sh1.UsedRange, Sh1.Columns(2))

    'Clear data in sheets
    Sh2.Cells.Clear
    Sh2.Range("B4") = "start"
    Sh3.Cells.Clear
    Sh3.Range("B4") = "start"

    'Clear autofilter
    If Sh1.AutoFilterMode Then Sh1.AutoFilterMode = False

    For Each R0 In R1
        Select Case Trim(R0.Value)
            Case Is = "Change"
                Intersect(R0.EntireRow, Sh1.Range("A:F,BL:BO")).Copy Sh2.Cells(Sh2.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            Case Is = "Early"
                Intersect(R0.EntireRow, Sh1.Range("A:D,O:R,BL:BO")).Copy Sh3.Cells(Sh3.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End Select
    Next R0

    Sh2.Range("B4") = ""
    Sh3.Range("B4") = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @O.PAL. How do I change the row (position) of the sheet where it gets copied too?

Comment: Well if you want it to start on 1st row of change/delay sheets, you'll have to delete that 1st blank row at the end of the macro : `Sh2.range("A1").entirerow.delete` and `Sh3.range("A1").entirerow.delete`. If you want to start at any other row, you can add `Sh2.range("A?")="-"` where `?` is the row you want minus one, same for Sh3.

Comment: It will always be row 5 Column B.

Comment: Brilliant. Thankyou!

Comment: Do I have to edit this code to get every row related to `Change` or `Delay`. It doesnt seem to be copying everything over?

Comment: Hmmm no, technically you should have everything. My best guess is to look for typo or unwanted spaces like "Change ". You can try replacing `Select Case R0.Value` by `Select Case trim(R0.Value)`

Comment: I've stripped it back to a test run as well and it only copies the most recently entered row. It doesnt copy all rows. There also needs to be a trigger to run the script.